# modifying pagenumbers in crossreferences

Tags: cross-referencing

I need to typeset crossreferences to pages, using `\pageref`, with wherever possible no more than two digits. For example:

```
pp. 1-23 
pp. 101-23   %(for 101-123)
pp. 101-105  %(not 101-05, because the second number starts with a zero)
pp. 101-222  %full range because 101-22 would be wrong
```

The crux is: `\pageref` just turns out 101-123; how can I modify this?

(Sorry no MWE, because I would need one with hundreds of pages...)
I looked at some packages, but none seem to offer the sort of thing I need.

Comment: I don't think this adds to clarity, nor it saves space.

Comment: If you refer to the practice of omitting digits in pagenumbers, it's just a publishing housestyle, whether or not I prefer it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a way to do it. I assume that page numbers are less than 999.

The arguments to `\pagerange` are the labels referring to the requested pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}

\newcommand{\pagerange}[2]{pp.~%
  \edef\tempa{\getpagerefnumber{#1}}%
  \edef\tempb{\getpagerefnumber{#2}}%
  \ifnum\tempa<100
    \tempa--\tempb
  \else
    \comparerange
  \fi}
\def\comparerange{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
  \noexpand\workondigits\tempa\tempb....\relax}\x}
\def\workondigits#1#2#3#4#5#6#7\relax{%
  \if#1#4%
    \if#50%
      #1#2#3--#4#5#6%
    \else
      #1#2#3--#5#6%
    \fi
  \else
    #1#2#3--#4#5#6%
  \fi}

\begin{document}
a\label{a}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{23}
b\label{b}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{101}
c\label{c}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{105}
d\label{d}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{123}
e\label{e}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{222}
f\label{f}

\newpage
\pagerange{a}{b}

\pagerange{c}{d}

\pagerange{c}{e}

\pagerange{c}{f}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Smolk [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Found out how to do that!  I now also have to do the same for pagereferences in the index; should I tag this question onto this one (as the issue is the same), or create a new question (leaning towards the latter)?

Comment: @Smolk A fresh question seems to be better, as I don't see how the same solution can apply.