# modifying pagerange in the index

Tags: indexing

In the index, my publisher requested to change the range of pages, with wherever possible no more than two digits. For example:

```
A, 1-23 
B, 101-23   %(for 101-123)
C, 101-105  %(not 101-05, because the second number starts with a zero)
D, 101-222  %full range because 101-22 would be wrong
```

Indexing just turns out 101-123, not 101-23; how can I possibly modify this?

This question is similar to [this one for pageranges in crossreferences](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117223/modifying-pagenumbers-in-crossreferences), but the required solution will be different I think.

Example:

```
\begin{theindex}

\indexspace
\textbf{Nonsense}
\subitem More nonsense   \hspace{6pt} 440
\subitem Some sense      \hspace{6pt} 347–350
\subitem Out of order    \hspace{6pt} 320-411
\subitem Beyond repair   \hspace{6pt} 100-105

\end{theindex}
```

Should become:

```
\begin{theindex}

\indexspace
\textbf{Nonsense}
\subitem More nonsense   \hspace{6pt} 440
\subitem Some sense      \hspace{6pt} 347–50
\subitem Out of order    \hspace{6pt} 320-411
\subitem Beyond repair   \hspace{6pt} 100-105

\end{theindex}
```

(Crucial is the second one, 347-50)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A style file for Makeindex can be used to get a markup command for the page numbers in the index file. In this case the style file is named `\jobname.mst` and therefore automatically by `makeindex` automatically.

```
%%% test.tex %%%
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.mst}
delim_0 ", \\ipage{"
delim_1 ", \\ipage{"
delim_2 ", \\ipage{"
delim_n "}, \\ipage{"
delim_r "--"
delim_t "}"
encap_infix "{\\ipage{"
encap_suffix "}}"
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{intcalc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ipage}[1]{%
  % The trick with \romannumeral removes an optional space
  \expandafter\@ipage\romannumeral-`\x#1----\@nil
}
\def\@ipage#1--#2--#3\@nil{
  \def\ipage@temp{#2}%
  \ifx\ipage@temp\@empty
    % case: no page range detected
    #1%
  \else
    % case: page range #1--#2
    \ifnum#1<100 %
      % case: no abbreviation needed, if first page < 100
      #1--#2%
    \else
      \edef\ipage@div@a{\intcalcDiv{#1}{100}}%
      \edef\ipage@div@b{\intcalcDiv{#2}{100}}%
      \ifx\ipage@div@a\ipage@div@b
        % case: pages differ in last two digits only
        \edef\ipage@mod@b{\intcalcMod{#2}{100}}%
        \ifnum\ipage@mod@b>9 %
          % case: second page is abbreviated and does not start with "0"
          #1--\ipage@mod@b
        \else
          % case: avoid that abbreviated number starts with "0"
          #1--#2%
        \fi
      \else
        % case: pages come from different "hundreds"
        #1--#2%
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\simpage}[1]{%
  \newpage
  \setcounter{page}{#1}%
  \null
}

\begin{document}

\printindex

\simpage{100}
\index{Nonsense!Beyond repair|(}
\index{Nonsense!Some sense|textbf}
\simpage{105}
\index{Nonsense!Beyond repair|)}
\index{Nonsense!More nonsense|(textit}
\simpage{320}
\index{Nonsense!Out of order|(}
\index{Nonsense!More nonsense|)textit}
\simpage{347}
\index{Nonsense!Some sense}
\simpage{348}
\index{Nonsense!Some sense}
\simpage{349}
\index{Nonsense!Some sense}
\simpage{350}
\index{Nonsense!Some sense}
\simpage{411}
\index{Nonsense!Out of order|)}
\simpage{440}
\index{Nonsense!More nonsense}
\end{document}
```

The generated file `test.mst`:

```
delim_0 ", \\ipage{"
delim_1 ", \\ipage{"
delim_2 ", \\ipage{"
delim_n "}, \\ipage{"
delim_r "--"
delim_t "}"
encap_infix "{\\ipage{"
encap_suffix "}}"
```

Commands (or `pdflatex` instead of `latex` or ...)

```
latex test
makeindex test
latex test
```

The index file `test.ind`:

```
\begin{theindex}

  \item Nonsense
    \subitem Beyond repair, \ipage{100--105}
    \subitem More nonsense, \ipage{\textit{\ipage{105--320}}}, \ipage{
                440}
    \subitem Out of order, \ipage{320--411}
    \subitem Some sense, \ipage{\textbf{\ipage{100}}}, \ipage{347--350}

\end{theindex}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: At first I could not get anything near this result because of the bidi package (it messed up the imakeidx index). I removed that package today, which suddenly gave me a recognizable index again. Yet TeX does not recognize \simpage from the answer above, while \setcounter{page} as a replacement does not yield the result. If I just copy your test.ind file, it does work; my .ind file is not created as expected, even from the test.tex above.

Comment: @Smolk: `\simpage` simulates a non-empty new page, it is just used for testing (instead of a larger complex document). I have added the missing definition.

Comment: Yes, it works as answered. And it also works with two indices and the package imakeidx. In that case, however, `\printindex` must apparently come at the end of the file (no result when up front)